# How to put 2 projects into one repository in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: git, tfs

I'm having problem to adding one Server side and one Client side into my repository on Team Foundation Server, how can i do this? i already had seen this before and i wanted to use, any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "client side" and "server side"? If you want more than one project in one Git repo, just commit them both to the same repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Git repository. I recommend that you can consider git submodules. The server and client side projects are in two repositories by link them through git submodules.

More information, you can refer to: [One TFS Build, Multiple Git Repositories with Submodules](https://www.benday.com/2016/11/04/one-tfs-build-multiple-git-repositories-with-submodules/).

If you still want to put 2 projects into one repository, you can clone a repository into a folder, then put server and client projects to that folder, then commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  **[team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project)** in TFS.

Not sure which one you are talking about, the normal projects or team projects.

- If you are talking about normal projects, just as Daniel mentioned in
  the comment, simply commit them both to the same repo. You will have
  a server side hold by TFS server, and a local side in your develop
  machine.
- If you are talking about team project, it's not able to handle a
  single repo across multiple team projects in TFS for now.